# How can I change this query into a subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

```
SELECT c.name, c.tel
FROM Customer c, Vehicle c, Hire h
Where c.cid=h.cid
AND v.vid = h.vid
AND (dropoff-pickup) > 1
AND v.make = 'Suzuki'
```

dropoff and pickup are just date fields

Comment: Why? What's the purpose?

Comment: A single query cannot be a subquery by definition.  It becomes a subquery when it's used within another query.

Comment: please don't join tables like this, it is blasphemy to the sql gods, use the JOIN keyword and ON statement instead of commas and where clauses

Comment: @Jeremy why? does it result in poorer performance? challenges in readability? fails to follow ANSI 92 standards? I'm not arguing the point, just pointing out the comment would be better if you explained **why** it's blasphemy, not just **what** needs to change.

Comment: @xQbert I don't know all the reasons I just know it's best practice to write them out and it surely helps the readability and will make mistakes in logic jump out more with more difficult queries

Comment: That's basically it.  Readability and complies with newer standards.  Most modern db engines will result in the same execution plan so it doesn't generally help performance.  The challenge is if you're working in a shop that only uses the pre ANSI 92 standards, or a non-modern database, adding ANSI 92 can actually DECREASE readability for those around (and depending on version may not work)   While I agree the ANSI 92 standards are easier to follow/debug, there are pro's/cons to both methods to call one bad without understanding context of use is ... well bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name, c.tel
FROM Customer c
JOIN hire h
ON c.cid = h.cid
JOIN Vehicle v
ON h.vid = v.vid
WHERE v.make = 'Suzuki' 
AND (h.dropoff-h.pickup) > 1
```

Not an answer to your question as you don't need a subquery here but please structure your query like this to make it more obvious what you are trying to do (you are getting the customer name and telephone number for vehicles with the make suzuki where the length of the hire was longer than 1 day right?)

Structuring your queries like this will make it more readable for people who don't know exactly what you are trying to do and will make finding mistakes in query logic easier for you or others

Comment: I just looked it up and appearantly there is no difference in speed between using comma joined tables with where clauses and tables joined using the join and on statements, but I must stress that at least when you are using a query with multiple where statements, write it like this so it keeps your join conditions and your where conditions separated and it will help a lot in readability of your query